# Why is document.cookie path coming in the value column?

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

I am trying to set document cookie path using the code

```
document.cookie="path=/ABC";
```

I was expecting this value to come in the **Path** column when viewing in Chrome's application tab. Instead it is simply saved as a key value pair:

[image]

I tried

```
document.cookie = "name=something;Path=/abc";
document.cookie = "name=something; Path=/abc";
document.cookie = "name=something, Path=/abc";
```

but none of them worked.

How should I change the code so that the value /ABC comes under **Path**

Comment: Keep in mind that cookie with path set to `/abc` is not accessible from your `/testchhin` location. I'd assume you to switch to `/abc` to check it's value.

Comment: @aleksxor this is just for testing cookie settings. I will have to change the value as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

remove your cookie manually and try smth like this:

```
document.cookie = "user=John; path=/; expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2022 03:14:07 GMT"
```

think, your problem is you mixing `key` and `path` in your first declaration, so when you trying to set cookie without `key` and it's `value`, your `path` automatically becomes the `key` and '/ABC' becomes the `value`.

also remember, that you can see all cookies you set when the cookie path and your browser's path are relevant. so your cookie to path `/abc` will be accessible at your `/abc` app route

also try to use this lib: https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/universal-cookie

it will be a helpful when you work with different cookies realisations in various browsers.